# How to use opencv-contrib modules in ROS Indigo?

Tags: ros, opencv, vision-opencv, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04. I installed the OpenCV 3 for ROS with apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-opencv3
```

However, I would like to use modules from the opencv_contrib repository (https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib.git). Is there an easy way to install and use these within ROS?

Initially, I had a standalone OpenCV 3 installation with the contrib modules, but I had to uninstall it because of referencing issues when using ROS.

EDIT: I think the installation of OpenCV 3 is discussed in point 5 of http://wiki.ros.org/vision_opencv, I actually ran this script, but I'm not sure what to do after this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219757/how-to-use-opencv-contrib-modules-in-ros-indigo?/) by [donald](https://answers.ros.org/users/24812/donald/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2015-10-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can use some contrib modules in ROS indigo as dnn and rgbd, but on the other hand sfm is no available.

---

Originally posted by [francisco.dominguez@urjc.es](https://answers.ros.org/users/21971/francisco.dominguez@urjc.es/) with karma: 16 on 2016-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vishal@leotechsa](https://answers.ros.org/users/37808/vishal@leotechsa/) on 2018-10-02**:
how you use the contrib modules in ROS indigo.